# Cannot remove additional information tab from product view in XML

Tags: catalog, xml

This is my xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
   <layout>
      <catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="product.info.tabs">
            <action method="unsetChild">
                <child>product_additional_data</child>
            </action>
        </reference>
       </catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

I clear the cache but nothing happens. I want to remove the additional info tab, but keeps the description. What should I change or check ? thx

**UPDATE**
This is the xml from catalog.xml base:

```
   <block type="catalog/product_view_attributes" name="product.attributes" as="additional" template="catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml">
                    <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
                    <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
                    <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Additional Information</value></action>
                </block>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using this xml code I manage to remove the additional info tab:

```
<catalog_product_view>
   <remove name="product.attributes"/>
</catalog_product_view>
```

Comment: This is the only answer that actually works for me (on 1.9.2.4 with RWD). Everyone else is saying to remove `product_additional_data`, but the name of the block that contains the tab is actually `product.attributes`. Worth noting that `<action method="unsetChild">` did not work either, neither when using the `product.attributes` block name, nor the `attributes` block alias.

Answer (score 0):

there are different way

**Method 1:**

```
<li><a href="#additional1" id="tab_additional1" class="tab" onclick="return false;” >Additional Information</a></li>
```

**Method 2**

If you want the ‘Additional Information’ not to be shown on the product description,

find out attributes which ‘Visible on Product View Page on Front-end’ and ‘Used in product listing’ is set to ‘Yes’,

and then turn them to ‘No’.

If all the attributes are set to ‘No’, then the ‘Additional Information’ tab will be disappeared.

**Method 3:**

local.xml

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="product.info.tabs">
        <action method="unsetChild">
            <child>product_additional_data</child>
        </action>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>

</layout>
```

**Method 4:**

commend `catalog.xml`

```
<action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog"><alias>additional</alias><title>Additional Information</title><block>catalog/product_view_attributes</block><template>catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml</template></action>
```

Comment: I want to  try just from xml , not phtml . I tried method 3 and it doesnt work

Comment: I don;t have in  base catalog.xml     <action method ......>

Comment: don't try your core file try your theme file

Comment: did you try try method 4

Comment: I don't have in my theme a catalog.xml . I have just a local.xml .

Comment: ok you just copy and paste your theme and try method 4

Comment: But in the base is missing this part: <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog"><alias>additional</alias><title>Additional Information</title><block>catalog/product_view_attributes</block><template>catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml</template></action>   CHECK my post again and see what i have in the base related to additional info

Comment: command this <block type="catalog/product_view_additional" name="product.info.additional" as="product_additional_data" />

Answer (score 0):

- **Your syntax is  wrong:**

  `<child>product_additional_data</child>`

**should be**

`<name>product_additional_data</name>`

- You have using `alias` name `instead of block name`

> `<block type="catalog/product_view_additional"
>       name="product.info.additional" as="product_additional_data" />`

### Here

**In your code you need to use :**

```
<reference name="product.info.tabs">                
        <action method="unsetChild"><name>product.info.additional</name></action>

</reference>
```

Comment: I tried your version and did not work. Any other idea is welcomed ! :)

Comment: srry for late responds, but it still does not work , with your updated answer :(